# OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user” when run spider script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I use anconda and python 3.7 in Windows 7.
I have write a spider script.

But when I tried to run it, error occurs: (using password: NO)")

It seems like the error is from system file and not my script, so I do not know how to fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


path = 'd:/data/app_qcc512x_qcc302x.html'
htmlfile = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

htmlhandle = htmlfile.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlhandle, 'lxml')




count = 0
result = pd.DataFrame({},index=[0])
result['author'] = ''
result['title'] = ''
result['source'] = ''
new = result
for item in soup.find_all('tr'):
if 'AU ' in item.get_text():
    author = item.get_text()
    new['author'] = author
elif 'TI ' in item.get_text():
    title = item.get_text()
    new['title'] = title
elif 'SO ' in item.get_text():
    source = item.get_text()
    new['source'] = source
    count += 1
    result = result.append(new,ignore_index=True)
print(count)


connect_info = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}? 
charset=utf8'.format("username", "password", "host", "port", "qcc")
engine = create_engine(connect_info)

df.to_sql(name='app_qcc512x_qcc302x',
      con=engine,
      if_exists='append',
      index=False,
      dtype={'IterationId': sqlalchemy.types.Integer(),
             'title': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=255)
             }
           )
```

error:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for 
user”
(using password: NO)")
```

Comment: You aren't passing a valid connection string: `'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}? charset=utf8'.format("username", "password", "host", "port", "qcc")` note, using `.format` makes no sense, you are simply passing string literals, you could have just written: `'mysql+pymysql://username:password@host:port/qcc? charset=utf8'` which should make it obvious why that won't work.

Comment: FWIW, as a general principle, keep in mind that using spyder to scrape web pages, and connecting to a database are, abstractly-speaking, two completely separate problems.  If in doubt, try writing the database connection code separately from your web scraper: Then you would see that you get the same error.  Knowing that it's a separate problem might make it easier to find solutions in the future, because you'll know that the problem is with the mysql engine for sqlalchemy, and nothing to do with spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I had not added `DB_USER=xyz` to the env file. I checked it with `echo $DB_USER` and found that the environment variable was empty. It then threw the same error:

```sh
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'xyz@MY_HOST' (using password: NO)")
```